# 2 tables in 2 different databases with different structures with same type of data to be synced

Tags: mysql, replication

My problem is I have a website that customers place orders on.  That information goes into orders, ordersProducts, ...etc tables.  I have a reporting Database on a DIFFERENT server where my staff will be processing the orders from.  The tables on this server will need the order information AND additional columns so they can add extra information and update current information

What is the best way to get information from the one server (order website) to the other (reporting website) efficiently without the risk of data loss?  Also I do not want the reporting database to be connecting to the website to get information.  I would like to implement a solution on the order website to PUSH data.

**THOUGHTS**

1. **mySQL Replication** - **Problem** - Replicated tables are strictly for reporting and not manipulation.  Example what if customer address changes? Need products added to order?  This would mess up the replicated table.
2. **Double Inserts** - Insert into Local tables and then insert into Reporting Database.  **Problem** - If for whatever reason the reporting database goes down there is a chance I lose data because the mySQL connection wont be able to push the data.  Implement some sort of query log?

**Both Servers use mySQL and PHP**

Answer (score 0):

Mysql replication sounds exactly like what you are looking for, I'm not too sure I understand what you've listed as the disadvantage there.

The solution to me sounds like a master to read-only slave where the slave is the reporting database.  If your concern is changes to the master then making the slave out of sync then this shouldn't be too much of an issue, all changes will be synced over.  In the situation of a loss of connectivity then the slave would track how many seconds it is behind master and execute the changes until the two are back in sync.

Comment: I understand I can update the tables on master BUT that seems  strange to be to have 2 different connections and swap between the 2.  One will be for updating and the other will be for selecting

Comment: I guess the term Reporting database is misleading.  I want to be able to process this information which may involve multiple steps

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you will be making selects and updates/inserts to BOTH databases and the two are required to stay in sync?

Comment: Sorry.  I want to be able to do the SELECTs & UPDATES on the reporting side.  I just need a way to transfer the RAW data from the orders site when the order is placed and then  basically do whatever I want with that data later on the reporting site

Comment: Ah right, I'm drawing a blank on how you would achieve that nicely, a trigger for inserts which inserts to another database would be possible but as far as I'm aware that will only work for local dbs on the same machine and not to another server as you said in your question.  You could I suppose set up replication then add a trigger on the slave to duplicate to another table which you could then manipulate.  Thats all I can think of but it would mean maintaining both the live data and the duplicate copy on the slave.

Comment: Or maybe have another table locally which uses the federated storage engine and do double inserts.  This would then push the insert to the reporting DB.